# C++ How to get a date using int values

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm making a future date calculator that uses localtime to get the current date, then gets a number of days from the user and calculates the date(Month and Day) after the addition of days

Where I'm having a problem is using my int value of newDate to allow for the proper use of tm_mon/tm_mday.

```
unsigned int newDate;

if (userInput > (365 - getDayOfYear())){ //If the intial date is greater than userInput
        newDate = (userInput - (365 - getDayOfYear()));
        cout << newDate << "\n";
    }
    else if (userInput < (365 - getDayOfYear())) { //If the intial date is less than userInput
        newDate = (getDayOfYear() + userInput);
        cout << newDate << "\n";

 time_t rawtime = NewDate; // The problem is over here
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);



    cout << "The date is ";
    cout <<  monthArray[timeinfo->tm_mon] << " " ;
    cout <<  dayArray[timeinfo->tm_mday] << "\n";
```

If it's not possible are there any alternatives?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you're running into? Edit: Ok, so you've added some more code randomly; the braces arent balanced and the variables names aren't the same. You need to say what the actual problem is. How your actual output different from your expected output is a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy way to do this using this in C++11/1u using this [header-only open source lib](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html):

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto currentDate = floor<days>(system_clock::now());
    auto diffDays = days{1000};
    auto futureDate = currentDate + diffDays;
    std::cout << futureDate << '\n';
}
```

Currently outputs:

```
2019-07-18
```

Here is a [wandbox link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PodYB3AwdYNFKbMv) where you can paste the above code and try it out yourself using various versions of gcc and clang.

This code will also run on recent versions of Visual Studio.

If you would rather do the calendrical computations yourself, [here are the underlying algorithms this library uses](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html).

Answer (score 0):

`time()` gives you current time in seconds since Epoch. So just add desired amount of days in future converted to seconds and use `localtime()` to get day and month:

```
 time_t timer = time( nullptr );
 timer += days * 24 * 60 * 60l;
 tm *ptm = localtime( &timer );
 // print it
```